# Are channels passed by reference implicitly

Tags: concurrency, go, channel, pass-by-reference

The go tour has this example for channels: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2

```
package main

import "fmt"

func sum(a []int, c chan int) {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range a {
        sum += v
    }
    c <- sum // send sum to c
}

func main() {
    a := []int{7, 2, 8, -9, 4, 0}

    c := make(chan int)
    go sum(a[:len(a)/2], c)
    go sum(a[len(a)/2:], c)
    x, y := <-c, <-c // receive from c

    fmt.Println(x, y, x+y)
}
```

The channel c is modified in the sum function and the changes persist after the function has terminated. Obviously c was passed by reference but no pointer to c was created. Are channels implicitly passed by reference in go ?

Comment: Yes, the reference types in Go are `slice`, `map` and `channel`. When passing these, you're making a copy of the reference. *(Strings are also implemented as a reference type, though they're immutable.)*

Answer (score 100, accepted):

<strike>Technically they're copied, because when you use `make`, you are allocating something on the heap, so it's technically a pointer behind the scenes. But the pointer type is not exposed, so they can be thought of as a reference type.</strike>

**EDIT**: From the spec:

> The built-in function make takes a type T, which must be a slice, map or channel type, optionally followed by a type-specific list of expressions. It returns a value of type T (not *T). The memory is initialized as described in the section on initial values.

A channel must be initialized before it can be used. `make()` does this, so it can be used as a reference type.

What this basically means is that you can pass it into a function and write to or read from it. The general rule of thumb is if you use `make`, `new` or `&`, you can pass it to another function without copying the underlying data.

So, the following are "reference" types:

- slices
- maps
- channels
- pointers
- functions

Only data types (numbers, bools and structs, etc) are copied when passing into a function. Strings are special, because they're immutable, but not passed by value. This means that the following won't work as expected:

```
type A struct {
    b int
}
func f(a A) {
    a.b = 3
}
func main() {
    s := A{}
    f(s)
    println(s.b) // prints 0
}
```

Comment: @tjameson: make doesn't imply heap allocation and slice is actually implemented as a struct and copied when passed around.

Comment: @squint - Right. By `array`, I meant `make([]int, 5)`, but I just realized this is more technically a slice. My bad.

Comment: @jnml - Reviewing the spec, I guess that's technically not the case. I'll edit.

Comment: Pointers aren't really reference types, they're value types which happen to function as references.

Comment: `slice` does not behave like 'opaque pointers' as `map` and `chan` do. If a function called with argument `a []string` changes it as `a = append(a, x)`, the caller will not see the change in length. Changes to pre-existing indices are visible (unless an `append` before it in same func causes reallocation).

Comment: So to be clear, are you saying that channels do not need to be passed as pointers, i.e. `foo(&myChan)` ,because they do not get modified, a.k.a. they are not data that is altered in function they are passed to. Instead, when you pass a channel by value, i.e. `foo(myChan)` you are just copying the address to the underlining pointer and passing that copied to the function. 

that makes sense to me.

Comment: @Subtubes correct, channels do not need to be passed as pointers, because the chan type is already a pointer to a struct (try `c := make(chan int, 0); log.Printf("%v", c)`). When calling a function, this pointer is copied and passed to the function. Whereas a slice type consists of a struct with (pointer, length, capacity) values. When calling a function, this (pointer, length and capacity) struct is copied and passed to the function. See [Go is pass-by-value — but it might not always feel like it](https://neilalexander.dev/2021/08/29/go-pass-by-value.html) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 17):

Everything in Go is passed and assigned by value. Certain built-in types, including channel types and map types, behave as opaque pointers to some hidden internal structure. And it is possible to modify that internal structure by operations on the channel or map. They start out as `nil`, which is analogous to the `nil` pointer.

Comment: Everything? Contradicts the chosen answer.

Comment: @TheRealFakeNews: Yes, everything. Of course, you might disagree if you have a different definition of pass-by-value. My definition is it is pass-by-value if simple assignment to the parameter variable in the called function has no effect on a passed variable in the calling scope. This semantic definition is consistent with the generally accepted statement (on this site and elsewhere) that Java only has pass-by-value. The passing semantics in Go are the same.

Answer (score 3):

You could say yes, but to say the "The channel c is modified in the sum function" isn't really the correct terminology. Channel sends and receives aren't really considered modifications.

Note that slices and maps behave in a similar way, see http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html for more details.

Also "passed by reference" implies that an assignment could be made to `c` in `sum` that would change it's value (as opposed to it's underlying data) outside of sum, which is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

Channel variables are references, but it depends on your definition of 'reference'. [Language specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types) never mentions reference types.

No channel (variable) is 'modified' in the `sum` function. Sending to a channel changes its state.

In other words, yes the channel is implemented as a pointer to some run time structure. Note that that's strictly necessary for the reference semantics.

EDIT: The above sentence was meant to read: "Note that that's *not* strictly necessary for the reference semantics.", ie. the word 'not' went MIA. Sorry for any eventually created confusion.