# in Go, what does channel assgiment mean?

Tags: go

i have this code,

```
// The prime sieve: Daisy-chain Filter processes.
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int) // Create a new channel.
    go Generate(ch)      // Launch Generate goroutine.
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        prime := <-ch
        print(prime, "\n")
        ch1 := make(chan int)
        go Filter(ch, ch1, prime)
        ch = ch1
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand what does channel assignment mean. For example ch=ch1,
what does this do? Deep copy or shallow copy?
what does go guarantee for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A channel is a reference type. See "[Are channels passed by reference implicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16590291/6309)".
(reference types: slices, maps, channels, pointers, functions)
And see "[Go - Pointer to map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11898286/6309)".

`ch = ch1` simply copy the reference value of `ch1` to `ch`.